# How to create a multidomain sitemap in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, sitemap, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, viewhelper

There's a multidomain website with different root levels in one TYPO3 instance.

I want to create a sitemap which includes all pages from all microsites in this instance. When I use a vhs viewhelper (`v:page.menu`) there's no way to set the entryLevel above the current root level.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, there's no way?

[ListViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/Menu/ListViewHelper.html) explains the attribute *entryLevel* to be the "optional entryLevel TS equivalent of the menu".

In TS you can set negative entryLevels to go behind the rootpage. This should work with the viewhelper, too.

Comment: v.page.menu.list offers with the parameter 'pages' a possibility to add a list of pages. That's a solution in this case, because I can select the root page and the microsites below (so a list of different id's). Selecting only the root page id and setting a negative entry level doesn't work. Somehow the tree is stopped for the microsites. Nevertheless it's a good workaround for my problem.